# Type of study design:

Tags: experiment-design

I have multiple dependant marketing variables measured on dichotomous scales and one independant variable with three levels (students, university personnel, both). I would like to define the type of study design in order to chose the correct statistical test for group differences. I want to see if the different marketing activities are different according to the main type of market (students, university personnel, both).

1) Between subject designs? 
2) Within subject designs?
3) Mixed designs?

What actually worries  me is the category "Both". If not I would hae already classified it as "Between subject design"

Can you help me with some ideas and suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: within group design is when you compare the performance of the same individual at different times, for example, pre and post-treatment. In this case there is only one assessment moment, is that right? So it does not matter whether you have people who share the share the characteristics of the other groups, they still represent another category.

Answer (score 0):

It is a between subjects design, since you won't measure the same subject multiple times. And subjects cannot be in two groups (only students, only university, student and university), so they are still discrete.